# ldap_sasl_bind_s(GSSAPI) - What should be provided in the credentials BERVAL structure

Tags: ldap, sasl, gssapi

I'm trying to use the [`ldap_sasl_bind_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366968%28VS.85%29.aspx) method from the Microsoft LDAP C SDK, with **GSSAPI** as the authentication mechanism. `ldap_sasl_bind_s` expects the credentials as a `BERVAL` structure, which is opaque.

Given a username (or a DN) and a password, **how do I get to the `BERVAL` structure** that I'm supposed to pass to `ldap_sasl_bind_s`?

The examples I've found so far

- are from other LDAP C SDKs - not the one from Microsoft
- use `ldap_sasl_bind_s` when SIMPLE authentication is desired - but I need to use GSSAPI
- use `ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s` when other SASL authentication mechanisms are desired. However, there is no `ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s` in the Microsoft SDK.

As a side note, the goal is to be able to bind over SASL to a variety of LDAP servers; for now: ActiveDirectory and OpenLDAP.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I managed to perform an LDAP SASL bind over GSSAPI, using `ldap_sasl_bind_s`. For those interested, here are some pointers.

For an abstract description of the actions a client and server need to perform during a GSSAPI SASL authentication, **"The Kerberos V5 ("GSSAPI") Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL) Mechanism"** RFC should be read; specifically, the 'Client Side of Authentication Protocol Exchange' section is of interest, because it gives an indication of the sequence of actions we need to perform to successfully bind to an LDAP server over Kerberos.

The credentials `ldap_sasl_bind_s` expects - their form and their meaning - depend on the actual authentication mechanism being used, which in our case is Kerberos.

In the Microsoft SDK, Kerberos is available through SSPI - which is roughly the Microsoft implementation of GSSAPI; the methods that are relevant for our particular case are: `AcquireCredentialsHandle`, `InitializeSecurityContext`, `DecryptMessage`, `EncryptMessage`

An LDAP SASL bind over Kerberos has 3 phases.

#### Phase 1

Call `AcquireCredentialsHandle` and `InitializeSecurityContext`.
Important notes here:

- pass to `AcquireCredentialsHandle` a pointer to a `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY` structure containing the actual credentials (realm, username, password), or `NULL` if the credentials of the current thread are to be used
- the target name should be an SPN mapped to the account under which the LDAP server is running
- when calling `InitializeSecurityContext`, mutual authentication must be requested.

If all important arguments are correct - valid credentials, valid SPN, `NULL` input token - the `InitializeSecurityContext` call should return `SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED` and properly fill the output token. The contents of this output token should go in the `BERVAL` structure `ldap_sasl_bind_s` expects as client credentials.

Call `ldap_sasl_bind_s` with the output token from `InitializeSecurityContext` as client credentials. If all arguments are correct - empty DN, GSSAPI as the mechanism name - the actual call should return `LDAP_SUCCESS` and the most recent LDAP error for the LDAP session should be `LDAP_SASL_BIND_IN_PROGRESS`.

As a side note, the most recent LDAP error for an LDAP session can be discovered by calling `ldap_get_option` on the session, with `LDAP_OPT_ERROR_NUMBER` as the option.

#### Phase 2

After the successful call to `ldap_sasl_bind_s`, its last argument points to a `BERVAL` structure containing the server credentials. The content of this `BERVAL` structure should now be used as the input token for the second call to `InitializeSecurityContext`.

This second call to `InitializeSecurityContext` should return `SEC_OK` and an empty output token.

This empty output token should be used as the client credentials for another call to `ldap_sasl_bind_s`. This second call to `ldap_sasl_bind_s` should return `LDAP_SUCCESS`, with the most recent LDAP error for the LDAP session being `LDAP_SASL_BIND_IN_PROGRESS`.

#### Phase 3

After the second successful call to `ldap_sasl_bind_s`, its last argument points to a `BERVAL` structure containing server data. This server data should be given as input to `DecryptMessage`. As specified in the previously mentioned RFC, the decrypted data must be 4 bytes long.

The client should build its reply according to the information in the same RFC.
**Note**: In my case, I omitted the authorization id mentioned in the RFC. To my understanding, an empty authorization id leads to the authentication id being used for authorization as well.

The reply the client built should then be passed as input to `EncryptMessage`. The output of the `EncryptMessage` call should then be passed as the client credentials for the third and final call to `ldap_sasl_bind_s`.

**Note**: The MSDN documentation for using `EncryptMessage` under Kerberos seems to be incomplete. Google's Code Search should assist with a working example. Also, for a working example of the flow described above, Samba's source code can be consulted.

Comment: Hi Catalina!

I have followed the steps you described, but I am having an issue I hope you can help me with.

The ldap_sasl_bind_s call on Phase 1 returns success, ldap_get_option returns LDAP_SASL_BIND_IN_PROGRESS, but the last parameter points to an empty BERVAL structure (zero size).

If I use that data to build the SecBufferDesc structure for Phase 2, the following call to InitializeSecurityContext returns SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN.

Is ldap_sasl_bind_s supposed to return an empty BERVAL or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Juan

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a missing ISC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH flag prior to the first call to InitializeSecurityContext.

Comment: +1 Good stuff.  So sad that not too many people in StackOverflow appreciate your work.

Comment: Hi Catalina! May be you can help me with my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14394642/475821
Thanks!

Comment: @esmirnov: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to successfully protect the LDAP communication that came after an ldap_sasl_bind_s(GSSAPI), and I eventually gave up. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Hi Catalina! I have followed the steps you described, and have some troubles with the last(third) call to ldap_sasl_bind_s 
May be you can help me with my question  here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554950/sasl-bind-over-gssapi-using-kerberos-credentials-with-ldap-sasl-bind-s-function,
 could you please have a look at it? As far as I understand I do everything like you have described here however, I get invalid credential error after last call of ldap_sasl_bind_s.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

According to this thread ( https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.active.directory.interfaces/browse_thread/thread/9c13fe85e520f0b4/820a136e032946e9?pli=1) there is a bug with ldap_sasl_bind_s returning empty server credentials in Windows XP. I have tested my application under Windows 2008 Server and the credentials are properly returned.

Comment: Just hit the same bug and spent a day trying to nail it down. Thanks for sharing, Juan!

Answer (score 0):

Article from [Sun](http://docs.sun.com/source/817-6707/functions.html#wp57022) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366968%28VS.85%29.aspx). Probably if you can try creating a sample program you may get the answers

[Another One](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33421045/ldap--ad-connection-using-gssspnego-sasl.aspx)

PseudoCode

```
struct berval   cred;
char mechanism[BUFSIZ];
getline( mechanism, sizeof(mechanism), stdin, "mechanism? " );
getline( passwd, sizeof(passwd), stdin,"credentials? " );
cred.bv_val = passwd;
cred.bv_len = strlen( passwd );
rc = ldap_sasl_bind_s( ld, dn, mechanism, &cred, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```