# What is the format for the cred parameter for ldap_sasl_bind_s?

Tags: ldap, kerberos, openldap

When using ldap_sasl_bind_s with a Kerberos credential file (/tmp/krb5cc_id), what do you use for the ber value?  Is it the name of the file?  Is it the contents of the file?

For example (this doesn't seem to work):

```
struct berval cred;

cred.bv_val = "/tmp/kr5cc_id";  
cred.bv_len = strlen(cred.bv_val);  
ldap_sasl_bind_s(ld, NULL, NULL, &cred, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Have you tried ldap_sasl_bind_s(ld, NULL, "GSSAPI", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)?

Answer (score 0):

`cred` parameters contain opaque data obtained from the layer implementing a particular SASL mechanism. Say, if you're using GSSAPI SASL mechanism, you're supposed to call out to some library (Cyrus SASL, for instance) and shovel the data between it and `ldap_sasl_bind()`. The data is opaque as far as `ldap_sasl_bind()` is concerned: it just embeds it into bind messages it generates and reads out from "bind-in-progress" messages it receives.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433553/720999) provides a fairly complete explanation.  It's specific to Microsoft's SSPI (which does implement `GSSAPI` (Kerberos V5), `NTLM`, `GSS-SPNEGO` and `DIGEST-MD5`).